# Can't convert 'DeferredAttribute' object to str implicitly

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

When Iam trying to get the degree of a student and do the return value with that code:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.student_subject + " " + Student.last_name
```

I got the above error message.
Here is the whole Django code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name


class Degree(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    student_degree = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_subject + " " + Student.last_name
```

the error is happening because I trying to inherite the return from the above class Student
And here is the error message:

```
TypeError at /admin/sellingportal/degree/

Can't convert 'DeferredAttribute' object to str implicitly

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sellingportal/degree/
Django Version:     1.10.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

Can't convert 'DeferredAttribute' object to str implicitly

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Muham\PycharmProjects\managementsite\managementstudio\sellingportal\models.py in __str__, line 22
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Muham\\PycharmProjects\\managementsite\\managementstudio',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 16 Sep 2016 01:04:08 +0200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.student_subject + " " + self.student_id.last_name
```

and all should be fine.

You cannot set Student.last_name because you have to show from which object, should the last name be taken from.

Comment: Mark as an answer, best wishes